# Groovy object with cycles as JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to use the default Json facilities to output an object as JSON. But unfortunately, the object in question actually has cycles in it. I need the JSON to either output `#ref` or simply prune it.

I have been working with the JsonGenerator and trying to define a custom converter that merely stops following an object serialization when it discovers something it has already encountered. I can't use a classic hashing structure because this would have the same problem: hence the use of an `IdentityHashMap`. Because I am basically trying to export a complicated structure from Jenkins I don't have the luxury knowing what field I can exclude (in fact, I am trying to determine what fields are available).

1. The first approach below generates a `NullPointerException` because apparently it doesn't handle null values (that makes no sense because that's a pretty common case).
2. So, I added `excludeNulls()` to the builder; same result.
3. Since I don't care what the output is for that key, as long as it doesn't produce an error, it's fine. I simply hard coded it to "#ref" and, well, that's all I get!
4. Then it occurred to me that, if it's not my case I should just delegate it to the original implementation. That continues to produce a stack overflow.

If the question isn't obvious, then it's this: **How do you take the below map structure and get it to output JSON**; pruning cycles if needed but I don't really care how.

```
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator.Converter

def loop = [
        loop: [:]
]

def thing = [
        foo:'hello',
        baz: [
                bat:loop
        ]
]
loop.loop = thing

new JsonGenerator.Options().addConverter(new Converter() {
    private seen = [:] as IdentityHashMap
    @Override
    boolean handles(Class<?> aClass) {
        true
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object o, String s) {
        if(! (seen[o]) && o){
            seen[o] = 'seen + o'
            o
        }
    }
}).build().toJson(thing).with { println(it)}
```

Comment: Do you get errors?  Or what is the question?

Comment: I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems `JsonGenerator` thrown NPE

when `Converter.convert(v,key)` returns null on original non-null value...

```
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator.Converter

def loop = [
        loop: [:]
]

def thing = [
        foo:'hello',
        baz: [
                bat:loop
        ],
        nnn: null
]
loop.loop = thing

new JsonGenerator.Options().addConverter(new Converter() {
    private seen = [:] as IdentityHashMap
    @Override
    boolean handles(Class<?> aClass) {
        true
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object o, String key) {
        if(o!=null){
            if( seen[o] ){
                //o = null //null instead of '<seen>' throws NPE
                o = '<seen>'
            }else{
                seen.put(o,true)
            }
        }
        return o
    }
}).build().toJson(thing).with { println(it)}
```